# Property 'email' does not exist on type '{setup():{email : Ref<string>; password: Ref<string> }}

Tags: typescript, firebase, vue.js

I'm currently trying to use vue js 3 with typescript in the composition API
i'm using firebase for authentication

```
<template>
      <input placeholder="Password" @input="this.password"/>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
export default {
setup() {
const router = useRouter();
const email = ref("");
const password = ref("");
const gender = ref("Male");
const registerUser = () => {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(getAuth(), this.email, this.password)
    .then((data) => { 
      router.push("/");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
return {
  email,
  password,
  gender,
  registerUser,
};
```

},

Error's I get for both email and password  :

> Property 'email' does not exist on type '{ setup(): { email: Ref; password: Ref; gender: Ref; registerUser: () => void; }; methods: {}; }'.

error I get in the browser while testing the feature

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email')

Comment: You need to type `email` here. Either with a custom interface or something simpler like a string as the error suggest.

Comment: where and how should I type email and password, because both of them have this error and I'm out of ideas now 
Btw thanks :)

Comment: I don't use Typescript myself but I'm sure that any tutorial around TS basics would be fine to solve that issue since this is the most common usage (types).

Comment: unfortunately my last plan was to ask this question in stackoverflow becuase I watched a lot of tutorials and none of them had any use
thanks anyways

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can google for some basics in english and that you get that right straight from the first few links. Otherwise, you can look directly at the firebase project too, probably not the only one struggling with that approach.

Comment: Ik that already if it could help me it would've done already 
take's less effort obviously

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Three things.
First of all, why are you passing a ref as your **@input** callback? and why are you writing it as **this**.password? In vue.js template tags you should not put this before setup variables. I guess what you wanted to do was something like:

```
<input placeholder="Password" v-model="password"/>
```

Secondly and again, you don't need to use **this** before email and password in your **createUserWithEmailAndPassword** arguments.

And thirdly, as your email and password are "Refs"", they are objects with proxies in your script and to access them, you should write:

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(getAuth(), email.value , password.value)
```

Comment: I fixed it before I saw your reply and yeah you're right about all three